# In fedora Linux, Waydroid opens in fullscreen mode, but in gnome the top panel is not hidden

Tags: linux, fullscreen, fedora, gnome, waydroid

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEsn1.jpg)

I tried dash to panel, but it breaks the interface. The icons in the application menu have a jerky animation. I do not know why this is happening.

Is there any extension that hides the top bar if the app is open to full screen?

Comment: try https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.